# Navigate from a UITabBarController to another UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have UITabBarController which has 1 2 3 and 4 scenes. On scene 2 I have Views on which I click and it should be navigated to another UITabBarController with another A, B, C and D scenes.

Problem is push is not working. I call my second UITabBarController from my scene 2.

```
CompanyDetailsTabBarViewController *controller = [self.storyboard     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:company_details_tab_bar_controller];
NSLog(@"1 2 3 %@ %@ %@ %@", controller, self.parentViewController, self.parentViewController.parentViewController, self);

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

I even tried

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

but this doesn't work either.

Comment: You having 2 tabbarController or a TabbarController with 4 tabs ?

Comment: @Vineesh I have 2 UITabBarControllers each having four tabs.

Comment: I am using tab bar controller to show four different types of information. On second tab, when I click that information I have to go to another UITabController. This particular information is then itself categorized as four different sub units i.e. tabs.

Comment: Why you are using 2 TabbarControllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's now how tab bar controllers are supposed to work. They're meant to be the root view controller of your app and are not designed to be pushed onto a navigation stack.

> Before creating a tab bar interface, you need to decide how you intend to use a tab bar interface. Because it imposes an overarching organization on your data,you should use one only in these specific ways:
>
> Install it directly as a window’s root view controller.
>
> Install it as one of the two view controllers in a split view interface. (iPad only)
>
> Present it modally from another view controller.
>
> Display it from a popover. (iPad only)

From [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3).

It sounds like presenting modally is the best solution for you.